# Impossible to hide series with highcharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I have a graph displayed dynamically by Highcharts (bundle Symfony 2) in Ajax and some buttons to hide/show series. When my chart is displayed for the first time, I arrive to hide or show my series with buttons.
When I refresh my tab in Ajax, my buttons doesn't work ; I don't have any Javascript errors, Highcharts said me that my serie is hidden but it's not the case.

```
// function to redraw my graph
function refreshTab()
{

          $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
        url: "{{path('MYPATH') }}", // path to my controller that use the bundle
      success:function(response){
          $('#graph').html(response);

      }
  });
}

// event to hide/show series    
$(document).on('click', '.btn_qualite', function (event) {
for (index in Highcharts.charts[0].series) {
    serie = Highcharts.charts[0].series[index];
    if (serie.name.indexOf($(this).attr("title")) >= 0) {
        if (serie.visible) {
            serie.hide();
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        } else {
            serie.show();
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Your situation is not that clear. What it might be is that you are creating a new chart but you are always referring to `charts[0]` in your button handler.

Comment: Oh yes it can be this but its bizarre because in my controller i create a new graphic object and i replace the content of my div

Comment: Each time you create a new chart in a place of the old one, the new element is added to the `Highcharts.charts` array and the previous elements of the array are `undefined`. So in case when a new chart is created and placed in the same container, for example three times, the `Highcharts.charts` looks like this: `[undefined, undefined, H.Chart]`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6v6buzd2/.